# What's wrong with my Bootstrap code?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

So I'm working on a simple landing page using Bootstrap as the framework. For the most part everything is ok. I'm having a problem where all the elements in the wrapping container div are taking up 100% of the viewport. I'd like them to have some margins on the left and right.

I can easily get it nice and centered on the page with left and right margins by setting a max-width of say 960px. However when I do that it messes up the responsiveness of the page.

When I set a max-width for the container and I make the window wide all of the columns stack vertically as if it were on a mobile device. Which I don't want.

Here is the current working version of the site: http://dev.mikefisherdesign.com/stackstrap
This doesn't have a max-width set so it takes up 100% of the view port (which I don't want)
But the columns work perfectly on this one.

Here is another version of the site: http://8310kirkwood.com/test.html

This one does have a max-width set, but again when I make the browser super wide it stacks into single column mode which I don't want.

I'm sure there is a simple fix for this I'm just kinda stumped.

Comment: Here at Stack Overflow, code is usually favored over a link to a website, because once the link has changed, the question will no longer have historical value. Visit [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for help with formatting code into your question. It may also be helpful to use a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to help illustrate your point.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrapping everything in

```
<div class="container-narrow"></div>
```

just change that to

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that earlier but then it always stays as a single vertical column. Here it is with just a regular container div

http://dev.mikefisherdesign.com/stackstrap/

Answer (score 0):

You need a container, you need row(s) in that container, and the columns within each row have to have spans (span3, span6, etc.) adding up to 12 to set their width.

Look at the source of this example: 
http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/342_bootstrap_carousel/Carousel-Files-COMPLETE/index.html

Comment: Actually this was not a very good answer, my apologies. Try starting your container div under the navbar instead of including it.

Comment: Yup I know how Rows and Spans work they're all setup properly in my HTML I believe. I think it has something to do with the CSS like I mentioned in my original question.

Comment: put the width: 960px and margin: 0 auto on "MyCarousel" instead of the container and I think that will give you what you want.